# Which is the correct Disk Used Size information getting from M_DISK_USAGE or M_DISKS view?

Tags: hana

There are 2 System Views provided by SAP Hana Database. M_DISK_USAGE and M_DISK

While comparing the two tables I came to know that USED_SIZE information of DATA,LOG,.....Usage Types are different in both tables.

Can someone please help me to understand, If I want to Monitor the Disk Usage of all usage types at the current time which view can I use to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

The question really is what you want to know.
If you want to know how large the filesystems of the HANA volumes is and how much space is left there, then **M_DISKS** is the right view:

show free disk space in [KiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte):

```
/hana/data/SK1> df -BK .
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      403469844K 134366892K 269102952K  34% /hana
```

compared to the M_DISKS view (sizes converted from bytes to KiB):

```
DISK_ID DEVICE_ID   HOST        PATH                            SUBPATH     FILESYSTEM_TYPE USAGE_TYPE  TOTAL_SIZE_KB   USED_SIZE_KB
1       113132      skullbox    /hana/data/SK1/                 mnt00001    xfs             DATA        403469844       134366892   
2       113132      skullbox    /usr/sap/SK1/HDB01/backup/data/             xfs             DATA_BACKUP 403469844       134366892   
3       113132      skullbox    /hana/log/SK1/                  mnt00001    xfs             LOG         403469844       134366892   
4       113132      skullbox    /usr/sap/SK1/HDB01/backup/log/              xfs             LOG_BACKUP  403469844       134366892   
5       113132      skullbox    /usr/sap/SK1/HDB01/skullbox/                xfs             TRACE       403469844       134366892
```

**M_DISK_USAGE** on the other hand shows what the HANA instance allocated in total grouped by usage types.